# What is the best combination of Docker file and SecurityContext Capabilities

Tags: security, dockerfile

I am having difficulty in concluding best combination of Security capabilities which we can configure in Pod yaml and Docker file settings. Dint get much help when i checked on the internet. I have Docker file like below. We had to introduce non root user to fix Vulnerability issues of the image.

```
RUN groupadd npsuser -g 10001
RUN useradd -u 20001 -g 10001 -o npsuser
RUN usermod -aG wheel npsuser
RUN echo -e "npsuser\tALL=(ALL)\tNOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/npsuser_sudo_for_me
RUN chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/npsuser_sudo_for_me
RUN chmod u+x /bin/sudo

USER npsuser
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sudo","-E","/bin/<cmd>"]
```

Having the above docker file, we were trying to update SecurityContent capabilities in order to tighten the security using below settings in yaml file

```
securityContext:
            runAsUser: 20001
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - "ALL"
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
```

But we are running into issues. It will be helpful if someone can point me to reference documentation which explains both of these things